# Angular: change in one field needs to get reflected in another

Tags: angular

I am relying on change event to capture changes in 2 input fields: one drop down gameTableTemplateId and one number type input field noOfRounds. Any changes should affect the 3rd input field noOfParticipants. Changes are getting reflected visually, but when I submit the form, these changes are not reflecting. For a ordinary input field the data is getting preserved. Here is my template file:

```
      <section class="content-wrap-with-left-nav" [ngClass]="toggleService.bodyStatus ? 'body- 
         expand' : 'body-collapse'">
      <div class="content-main">
      <div class="content-outer">
       <div class="top-heading">
          <h2 class="title">Create Tournament</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="CTT-from-wrap">
          <form  [formGroup]="tournamentTypeForm" 
            (ngSubmit)="template(tournamentTypeForm.value)">               
            <div class="content">
               <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="gameTableTemplateId" 
                         class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Game Template Id</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                     <select class="form-control 
            {{tournamentTypeForm.controls['gameTableTemplateId'].errors &&                     
              tournamentTypeForm.controls['gameTableTemplateId'].errors.required ? 
                'required-highlight' : ''}}"
                        id="gameTableTemplateId" formControlName='gameTableTemplateId' 
                name='gameTableTemplateId'
                        (change)="onChangeGameTemplate($event.target.value)">
                        <option [ngValue]=null>Select a game template id</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let e of gameTableTemplateIds" 
                           [value]="e">{{e}}</option>
                     </select>
                     <div class="form_error_blk"
                        *ngIf="tournamentTypeForm.controls['gameTableTemplateId'].errors 
                           && tournamentTypeForm.controls['gameTableTemplateId'].errors.required">
                        <span class="form_error_class">* Game Template Id required</span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="tournamentName" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                     <input type="text" name="tournamentName" class="form-control" 
                     formControlName="tournamentName" />
                  </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
               <label for="noOfRounds" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">No of rounds</label>
               <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="number" name="noOfRounds" [value]="noOfRounds"
                  (change) = "onChangeNoOfRounds($event.target.value)"
                  class="form-control" formControlName="noOfRounds" />
               </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
               <label for="noOfParticipants" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">No of 
                participants</label>
               <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="number" name="noOfParticipants" 
                        [value] = "noOfParticipants" readonly="true"
                  class="form-control" formControlName="noOfParticipants" />
               </div>               
            </div>
            </div>  
             <div class="btn-wrap">
               <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
               <button type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
            </div>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </section>
```

And the component file is:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tournament-creation',
    templateUrl: './tournament-creation.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tournament-creation.component.scss']
  })
  
export class TournamentCreationComponent implements OnInit {
    domainUrl: string = "real";
    domain:number = 2;
    tournamentTypeForm: FormGroup;
    tournamentName: string;
    tournamentStartDate: Date = new Date();
    tournamentEndDate: Date;
    registerByDate: Date;
    noOfParticipants: Number;
    tournamentFees: Number;
    firstPrize: Number;
    secondPrize: Number;
    thirdPrize: Number;
    gameTableTemplateIds: any[];
    createdThrough: string;
    gameTemplateId: Number;
    seatMapping: any = {};
    gameTableTemplates: GameTableTemplate[] = [];
    seatingCapacity: number;
    noOfRounds: number = 1;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if(this.router.url.includes('/dashboard/real-money')){
            this.domainUrl = "real";
            this.domain = 2;
         }else if(this.router.url.includes('/dashboard/play-money')){
            this.domainUrl = "play";
            this.domain = 1;
         }
         this.templateservice.getTournamentListdata(this.domain).subscribe(response => {
           this.gameTableTemplateIds =  response.body["responseObject"].map(el => el.gameTableTemplateId );
           console.log("gameTableTemplateIds",this.gameTableTemplateIds);
           this.gameTableTemplates = response.body["responseObject"];
          
           for(let gtt of this.gameTableTemplates){
               this.seatMapping[gtt.gameTableTemplateId] = gtt.seatingCapacity;
           }
           
        });
        this.tournamentTypeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          gameTableTemplateId: [null, Validators.required],
          tournamentName: [null, Validators.required],
          tournamentStartDate: [null, Validators.required],
          tournamentEndDate: [null, Validators.required],           
          registerByDate: [null, Validators.required],
          noOfParticipants: [null, Validators.required],
          tournamentFees: [null, Validators.required],
          firstPrize: [null, Validators.required],
          secondPrize: [null, Validators.required],
          thirdPrize: [null, Validators.required],
          createdThrough: [null, Validators.required],
          noOfRounds: [null, Validators.required]

        }); 

    }
    constructor(
      private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
          private router: Router,
          public toggleService: ToggleService,
      private templateservice: TemplateMasterDataService,
    ) {}

  template(data) {
    console.log("data", data);
  }

  onChangeGameTemplate(event){
    console.log("event", event);
    this.seatingCapacity = this.seatMapping[event];
    console.log("seatingCapacity", this.seatingCapacity);
    this.noOfParticipants = Math.pow(this.seatingCapacity,this.noOfRounds);
    console.log("noOfParticipants", this.noOfParticipants);
  }

  onChangeNoOfRounds(event){
    this.noOfParticipants = Math.pow(this.seatingCapacity,event);
    console.log("noOfParticipants", this.noOfParticipants);
  }

}
```

When I am submitting this form derived field's value is blank.

**Update**
StackBliltz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pah4tj?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: can you please provide stackblitz url ? By reading this code its difficult to understand problem.

Comment: @PiyushJain added stackblitz link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SubhenduMahanta, **remove** the `[value]` of the inputs. You has a FormControl. So to give value to the formControl use [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setvalue)

```
onChangeGameTemplate(event){
  this.seatingCapacity = this.seatMapping[event];
   //see that you can use this.tournamentTypeForm.value.noOfRounds
   const noOfParticipants = Math.pow(this.seatingCapacity,
      this.tournamentTypeForm.value.noOfRounds);
  this.tournamentTypeForm.get('noOfParticipants').setValue(noOfParticipants);
}

onChangeNoOfRounds(event){
  const noOfParticipants = Math.pow(this.seatingCapacity,event);
  this.tournamentTypeForm.get('noOfParticipants').setValue(noOfParticipants);
}
```